# How to integrate digital fingerprint reader into an angular application

Tags: angular, angular8

you a biometric fingerprint reader U.are.U 4500 and I want to integrate it to my angular application

I have these dependencies

> @digitalpersona/core @digitalpersona/devices @digitalpersona/services

but I don't know how to use them, does anyone have an example code?

Comment: did you find any solution? I am trying to do the same but I think I will create a java application with a webview, then I will share data between the angular application and the host hava application